# Special handling and timeline for getting Android Advertising ID on Android 12 devices

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-12, google-advertising-id

I have come across multiple sources that starting in late 2021, Android Advertising ID will not be available (it will be String of zeros) on Android 12 devices when users will be opt-out of Ads personalization. One of the good sources is:
https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-services-delete-ad-id-opt-out-personalization/

To ensure the proactive handling of my app monetization for the Android 12 devices, I just verified on Pixel 4 device (running Android 12 OS) and I am able to get the Android Advertising ID after opt-out of Ads personalization. And that even without doing any extra step to target API 31 (Android 12) such as without adding any extra permission of AD_ID. Is there any clear timeline, by when it will be an effect at least for Android 12 devices? This will help us to plan the deployment in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The official timeline for Android 12 devices is 'late 2021', without further details.

After that, it will expand to all devices that support Google Play starting April 2022.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Remember that if you are using AdMob, you don't need to add the AD_ID permission explicitly. The AdMob SDK already adds this permission for you.

Answer (score -1):

Add AD_ID permission in your manifest

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31460944)